# Deseo actualizar el campo "estado" de todos los registros de mi tabla convocatoria cuando el atributo "fecha_vencimiento" sea igual a la fecha actual

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

mi código HTML de la vista

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed table-hover"><!--agregamos la tabla-->
                <thead>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Descripción</th>
                    <th>Categoria</th>
                    <th>PDF</th>
                    <th>Fecha Publicación</th>
                    <th>Fecha Vencimiento</th>
                    <th>Estado</th>
                    <th>Opciones</th>
                </thead>
                @foreach ($convocatorias as $conv)
                <tr >
                    <td>{{$conv->idconvocatoria}}</td>
                    <td>{{$conv->descripcion}}</td>
                    <td>{{$conv->categoria_convocatoria}}</td>
                    <td><a class="fa fa-file-pdf-o colorplomo" target="_blank" href="{{asset('archivos/pdf/'.$conv->archivo)}}"> PDF</a></td>
                    <td>{{$conv->fecha_publicacion}}</td>
                    <td>{{$conv->fecha_vencimiento}}</td>
                
                    <td class="{{strtolower($conv->estado)}}">{{$conv->estado}}</td>

                    <td>
                        <a href="{{URL::action('ConvocatoriaController@edit', $conv->idconvocatoria)}}"><button class="btn btn-primary">Editar</button></a>
                        <a href="" data-target="#modal-delete-{{$conv->idconvocatoria}}" data-toggle="modal"><button class="btn btn-danger">Eliminar</button></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @include('convocatoria.locacion.modal')
                @endforeach
            
</table>
```

Mi Controller, estoy trabajando con laravel 5.2

```
public function store (ConvocatoriaFormRequest $request)
{
    $convocatoria=new Convocatoria;
    $convocatoria->idpersona=$request->get('idpersona');
    $convocatoria->descripcion=$request->get('descripcion');
    $convocatoria->categoria_convocatoria=$request->get('categoria_convocatoria');
    $convocatoria->estado= 'VIGENTE';
    $mytime = Carbon::now('America/Lima');
    $convocatoria->fecha_publicacion=$mytime->format('Y-m-d H');
    $datee = Carbon::parse($request->get('fecha_vencimiento'));
    $convocatoria->fecha_vencimiento=$datee->toDateTimeString();

    if (Input::hasFile('archivo')){
     $file=Input::file('archivo');
     $para_extencion=$file->getClientOriginalName();
     $extension = pathinfo($para_extencion, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
     $nombre_archivo="pdf_".$request->get('categoria_convocatoria')."_".time().".".$extension;
     $file->move(public_path().'/archivos/pdf/',$nombre_archivo);
     $convocatoria->archivo=$nombre_archivo;
    }
    $convocatoria->save();
    return Redirect::to('convocatoria/locacion');

}
```

En la base de datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi vista

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente usando triggers y procedimientos almacenados pero lo que me interesa es que se se actualicen en tiempo real o cada cierto tiempo los estados de todos los registros de VIGENTE a FINALIZADO cuando el atributo "fecha_vencimiento" sea igual o menor a la fecha actual

Comment: Debes crear un evento programado, primero setea el servidor con la sentencia `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;` y luego programa la tarea a realizar. [aqui](https://donnierock.com/2013/01/30/eventos-en-mysql-planificar-tareas-fecha/) te dejo un link para que veas como se hace.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible hacerlo en Laravel, con una [tarea programada](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling) y ejecutando un [comando personalizado](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#command-structure) que debes crear.

En el procedimiento handle() de tu comando, podrías terner algo como:

```
$convocatorias = Convocatoria::where('fecha_vencimiento','<',Carbon::now())->get;

foreach($convocatorias as $convocatoria){
   $convocatoria(['estado']=>'No vigente')->save();
}
```

Podrías incluir un Log dentro del proceso para ver qué convocatorias se han actualizado. Este comando se podría ejecutar 1 vez al día.

Y siempre tendrías tus convocatorias actualizadas.